# JWT en API PHP MVC

Tags: php, api, mvc, jwt

es la primera vez que pregunto en este foro, les pido disculpas si me explayo mal...
Bueno mi problema es el siguiente:
Hice una api en php pero quiero asegurarla con jwt, estuve leyendo en varios lados y viendo tutoriales pero no logro entender.
Por lo que e visto el token hay que generarlo cuando un usuario se autentica y hay que guardarlo en la base de datos.

```
 public function jwt ($id,$email){
     $time = time();
     $token = array(
      "iat"=>$time,
      "exp"=>$time + (60),
      "data"=>[
        "account"=>$id,
        "email"=>$email
      ]);

     return $token;
    }
     public function login()
        {
    
         
            if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $nick = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $user = $this->modelUser->getAccount($nick);
                $passwordBase = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($password)));
    
                if ($user && $user->password == $passwordBase) {
                  $key = "prueba";
                  $token =  $this->jwt($user->login,$user->email);
                  $jwt = JWT::encode( $token,$key,'HS256');
                  $this->modelUser->updateJWT($jwt,$token['exp'],$token['data']['account']);
    
             
                    $this->userHelper->login($user);
                    header("Location:" . BASE_URL);
                  }else {
                    header("Location:" . BASE_URL . "showlogin?error=true");
                }
                }else {
                    header("Location:" . BASE_URL );
                }
            }
```

Acá cuando se inicia session en el proyecto se genera el token y se almacena en la base de datos y tambien la fecha de expiracion. pero ahora es cuando se me complica porque no se que hacer con el token en la api. que es lo que controlo para poder dar una respuesta en la api?
use la funcion JWT:decode($token,key,'algoritmo') pero me tira un error, mire en el metodo y creo que es porque le mando el token entero y no el payload, osea que tengo que hacer explode(".",$token) y mandarlo.
En fin no se que controlar para poder dar una respuesta o no. Controlo el token que tengo guardado en la base de datos con que?

imagen de la tabla de usuarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explayado bien xd
desde ya muchas gracias y un saludo atentamente !

Comment: No se porque no se ve el saludo, pero en el principio de la pregunta salude jajaj

Comment: Antes que nada, ¡Bienvenido a SOes!. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: El token no es necesario guardarlo... el token debe enviártelo el cliente en cada petición, tu lo único que tienes que hacer es validar que el token es correcto, que no está caducado y que el usuario tiene permisos para hacer lo que está pidiendo hacer. Y todo eso se hace con los datos que trae el token en si, no necesitas acceder a la base de datos cada vez a ver nada. Se supone que un JWT lleva un payload con lo necesario para verificar lo indicado arriba, así como una firma que permite comprobar que no se ha modificado el payload del mismo.

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo a programar, perdon si lo que respondo es cualquier cosa, entonces genero el jwt en javascript para mandarlo en la consulta y en la api verifico si es correcto para dar una respuesta? si es asi estoy complicado porque mi autenticacion es por php y no puedo llevar la data del usuario a js. se puede llevar a js pero los datos sensibles estaran a la vista

Comment: No, tienes mal el concepto. Desde JS se hace el llamado al endpoint de login, PHP lo procesa, genera un token y lo manda al cliente (no lo almacena en ningún lado)... El cliente lo recibe y lo almacena, y en cada petición siguiente debe mandar su token. El servidor recibe ese token en cada peticion, y si es valido, puede confiar en que el token es legítimo, porque viene firmado por el mismo servidor

Comment: Ya entendi, estaba mal del concepto si graciasss! pero tengo una duda mas, es viable almacenar el token del cliente en una cookie?